# iOS - Does setDefaultTimeZone handle daylight saving and timezone offset automatically?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, dst, nstimezone

Server currently store date in UTC and in the app user has option to select any timezone.

```
[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:selectedTimeZone]]
```

This will override the local timezone. Do I still need to handle anything in `NSDateFormatter` ?

```
setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```

I think I don't need to call `setTimeZone` in `NSDateFormatter` if I override defaulttimezone.

And `[NSDate date]` will then return proper current date or it will be absolute time ?

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened?

Comment: Not yet.. We have got one bug at server side. Instead of UTC, server was sending dates in different timezone. I would be working on UTC to localtimezone plus other timezone conversion in next couple of days

Comment: I saw your website - Code of Matt featuring timezone. Do you have suggestion how to handle server UTC to different timezone conversion and  again converting back to UTC while sending back to Server ?

Comment: Please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for this, and include details so the question is answerable.  Preferably, you should search first to see if your question has already been asked.  Chances are, it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few related questions here.

> This will override the local timezone. Do I still need to handle anything in `NSDateFormatter`?

You don't need to set the time zone, because if you don't, it uses the default value when the date formatter was created.

> I think I don't need to call setTimeZone in NSDateFormatter if I override defaulttimezone.

True, but if you ever change the default time zone, you need to create a new `NSDateFormatter`, because it doesn't notice that the default has changed. Or you could just change the date formatter's time zone any time you would change the default.

> And `[NSDate date]` will then return proper current date or it will be absolute time ?

The results of `[NSDate date]` are completely unaffected by the default time zone. `NSDate` has no time zone, so you get the same results even if you change the default.

> Does setDefaultTimeZone handle daylight saving and timezone offset automatically?

**If the time zone uses daylight saving time**, then yes. Otherwise no. That seems obvious but keep in mind that zones like `GMT-0500` don't have daylight saving time even though zones like `America/New_York` do.